# Clone and insert with jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     var clone = $("#me_flash_0").clone(true);

     if($('video').attr('class') == "pause_0"){
          $("#me_flash_0").remove();    
     }

     $('.top_item img').click(function(){
            $("#me_flash_0_container").html(clone);
            $(this).hide();     
     });

}
```

`#me-flash_0` is an `<embed>` element. And `#me_flash_0_container` is the wrapping container. The problem is that the cloned object seems to be empty. `html(clone)` has no effect.

Firebug does not show any error.

Here is the relevant html

```
<div id="me_flash_0_container" class="me-plugin">
   <embed id="me_flash_0">
</div>
<video class="pause_199" width="586px" height="440" src="some link" autoplay="true" tabindex="0" style="display: none;"></video>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with jQuery and cloning object elements.

See http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10324

And a possible way of working around this is to copy the content of the object's parent container into a hidden textarea and then using this textarea's val() to clone a new object.

See a similar approach here: [Cloning a silverlight embed object results in an empty white element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795020/cloning-a-silverlight-embed-object-results-in-an-empty-white-element)

Comment: This seems the way to go! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

         var clone = $("#me_flash_0").clone(true);

         if($('video').attr('class') == "pause_0"){
              $("#me_flash_0").remove();    
         }

         $('.top_item img').click(function(){
                $("#me_flash_0_container").children().remove();
                $("#me_flash_0_container").append(clone);
                $(this).hide();     
         });

    });
```

<del>As @techfoobar wrote, you can't use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to append a jQuery object. You were also missing an end parentheses at the end of the JavaScript.</del>

**Edit:** See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492181/jquery-cloning-and-removing-div-doesnt-add-div-back-in/11492210#comment15179565_11492210) on a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

a) `clone` is a full jquery extended element, not a html string. It should work if you do `.append(clone)` instead of `.html(clone)`

b) `clone` is declared local to the `ready(..)` function. You might need to move it out into a global variable since you do not know in advance when the click event handler is triggered

Comment: thanks for the information, however it does not fix the problem

Comment: can you post relevant HTML too? Another fix that might help is changing `.attr('class') == "pause_0"` to `.hasClass('pause_0')` since it'll work even if there are multiple classes in your 'video' element. Also i assume you are using the `<video></video>` tag here. Other wise, you might have missed a `#` or a `.` before the 'video' in the selector.

Comment: I posted the relevant html. There is no problem with the if condition.

Comment: Cloning something then inserting it via `append()` (or related method) should indeed clone an element, and does for me. What's not working when you try it?

Answer (score 0):

The issues i see that might be causing this ...

- You are caching the object on DOM ready.
  The object seems to be empty on start from the relevant code and that is what gets cached in the variable. (*you should add a closing `</embed>` tag as well*).
  I do not know what is supposed to appear in the `embed` element so not sure if the fact that nothing happens is the expected or not functionality..
- the `$('video').attr('class')` will return the classes applied to the **first** `video` element in the DOM. In the example code the `class_199`. But you compare with `class_0` so it will never match and not remove the `#me_flash_0` element.